# Is it possible to integrate with Sagepay Virtual Terminal using PHP?

Tags: php, terminal, virtual, opayo

I'm crating a Sagepay Direct implementation for a client, which deals with taking deposits and payments, as well as refunding deposits. This is fine for online payments, but the client also takes phone payments through Sagepay's [Virtual Terminal](http://www.sagepay.com/telephone-payments).
I would like to handle these payments through my system, which would allow a higher percentage of the refunds to be automated but, despite searching Sagepay's resources, Google, and SO, I can't find any information at all on integrating with the terminal.

So, what I would like to know is:

1. Is it possible to integrate in this way, and if so are there some resources I'm missing?
2. If there's no official API, would Sagepay implement anything that would prevent automating the process through CURL or a similar technology.

I have worked with Sagepay (both Direct and Form) before and am quite familiar with the online payment side of things, but not familiar with the Terminal.

Comment: I have integrated Sagepay using 'form integration'.   It's working fine on localhost but says 'An unexpected error seems to have occurred' when I test it on live server.       Can u please guide me on this if your Sagepay is working fine?!         P.s. I've cross checked my database credentials.         I have downloaded php sdk from: http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/9981/download-document/VspPHPKit.zip?token=IWw01ZMqSq6EQ-shgoJZql3_r4O47pifItd7p4wn_7Y

Comment: Well, I'm sure that Sagepay has changed a lot in the past four years, but it sounds very much like your server's IP address or FQDN isn't listed in the Sagepay security settings as an endpoint. Log in to the Sagepay portal and check the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I talked to Sagepay support and the answer is far simpler than I was expecting. I don't need to integrate with Terminal, I just have to use the standard integration and change the value of AccountType to 'M'.